# Adding custom text in pdf generated by datatables

Tags: datatables

I want to know if it is possible to add custom text in pdf generated by datatables plugin?

Currently I used "sTitle" and "spdfMessage" but i still got issues on it,I want to display it in a center and I also want to add footer text. How can I possibly do this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First include cdn js files for datatable in footer and don't forget to include its css in header

```
<script scr="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.18/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(function () {
          $('#example1').DataTable({
            order: [],
            columnDefs: [ { orderable: false, targets: [0] } ],
            'searching'   : true,
            'scrollY'     : true,
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            buttons: [
                'copyHtml5',
                'excelHtml5',
                'csvHtml5',
                'pdfHtml5',
                {
                    extend: 'print',
                    messageTop: 'Hi all i'm web developer',
                    title:"Welcome to Project "
                }
            ],
            'scrollY'     : true,
            'paging'      : true,
            'lengthChange': true,
            'info'        : true,
            'autoWidth'   : true,
          })

        })
    </script>
```

create page with table its id will `example1`.
buttons will appear on the top of data table try to click on print button
it will display you data table with title **Welcome to Project** 
and message in the top with **Hi all i'm web developer**

[This Also could help](https://datatables.net/reference/button/pdf)

Answer (score -2):

I have added custom header and footer in PDF. Please ping me if you still looking for help on this.

Comment: A ping to u... i m trying to do